# Can there be more than one value for scalars between lines that intersect?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, systems-of-equations

5. Determine the intersection point of the line through the points (1,−2,13) and (2,0,−5) and the line given by r(t)=⟨2+4t,−1−t,3⟩ or show that they do not intersect.

I simply treated each point as a position vector and subtracting the second point vector from the first, I get vector

$$\vec{v} = t<-1, -2, 18> $$

where t is some scalar.

Using the second point of  the first line ie. (2, 0, -5) I get the vector:

$$ \vec{r(t)} = <2 - t, -2t, -5 + 18t> $$

Now I simply converted the vector into a parametric equation:

x = 2 - t

y = -2t

z = -5 + 18t

I also did the same with the given line vector except instead of using t, I called it

$$t_{2}$$

$$  x = 2+4t_{2} $$
$$  y = -1-t_{2} $$
$$  z = 3 $$

if they do intersect there will be some value t and t2 for which all x y and z components are equal.

Now I got t2 = -1/9 and t=4/9 but my textbook got t=5/9 because it used the first point instead of the second. Am I still correct? since t=4/9 satisfied the condition for both lines intersecting, ie. had exactly the same points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. And, since you have determined that the lines do intersect, I think that correct answer (both from you and from the textbook) should be something lie “Yes; they intersect at $\left(\frac{14}9,-\frac89,3\right)$.” This is so because different persons will parametrize the the line through the points $(1,−2,13)$ and $(2,0,−5)$ in different ways.

Comment: okay thank u. i just wanted to make sure. idk why someone downvoted u. i know my question might seem naive or inexperienced but i just started learning vectors

Comment: My answers get downvoted all the time. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: lol on stackoverflow i answer questions people dont like because it seemed lazy but the fact is even though so many people know how to code theres still people trying to learn every day and i only answer if i think its reasonable for a beginner. thanks again man

Comment: also actually i have one more quick question. if i have points that lie on the same plane that doesnt necessarily make them parallel right?

Comment: I cannot answer that question, since I do not know what parallel points are.